# Laravel add column to collection from another model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I there any way to add a column from another table to a Laravel collection and then only render it in the resource if it exists?

My current query is as follows;

```php
$projects = Project::query()
    ->where('email', $request->user()->email)
    ->get();

return ProjectResource::collection($projects);
```

There is a `BelongsTo` relationship on the Project model which is for a designer;

```php
public function designer(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Designer::class);
}
```

The project query at the top only returns the designers id, but i would also like to include that designers name in the collection, the designers name exists on the Designer model as `name`.

I am also using the ProjectResource multiple times around the place, so is it possible to only include that designers name in the resource when it exists in the collection?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try in ProjectResource class addd 'name'=>$this->designer->name

Comment: Why have you not simply included your desired data in `ProjectResource::__toArray()`???